# How to hide all rows which have blank cells in a certain column?

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am trying to hide all rows which have blank cells in a certain column (Column H in the SOW tab).

This same macro (different rows but same syntax) worked on the third tab in this workbook. I checked, each row in the range is correct. Could it be that the range is too long?

```
Sub HideRowsInSOW_LOOP()
Dim r As Range, c As Range
Set r = Range("H27:H46,H48:H67,H69:H88,H90:H109,H111:H130,H132:H151,H153:H172,H174:H193,H195:H214,H216:H235,H237:H256,H258:H277,H279:H298,H300:H319,H321:H340,H342:H361,H369:H388,H390:H409,H411:H430,H432:H451,H453:H472,H474:H493,H495:H514,H516:H535,H537:H556,H558:H577,H579:H598,H600:H619,H621:H640,H642:H661,H663:H682,H684:H703")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each c In r
    If c.Value = 0 Then
        c.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Else
        c.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
Next c
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

When running this, I get the following error:

> run-time error '1004' error message: Method 'Range' of object
>   '_Global' failed

I have a much longer macro which serves the same purpose successfully and am worried about it slowing down my workbook/keep hearing that loop is better anyway.

Comment: Your string is too long. With some careful testing, it seems the limit is 255 characters. You will have to find an alternative.

Comment: Seeing as how your range string is exceeding 255 chars, it would be of use to tell us how you construct this range. If it is done dynamically through code, you might be better off using another method with variables or something such.

Comment: I tried breaking it in two parts and using `Union` to join the both, it works but the second part is only added till the total join instances are 18. Not sure what is with that number, maybe the total length of 255.

Comment: Thanks @Tim Stack. That's what it started to seem like so I divided this macro up into two since this hides blank rows in two tables in the SOW tab. Using the same syntax but for each table separately and then using a macro which calls both as the one to assign to the macro button worked for me. If there is a better way to write such a macro with such a large range, I'd really appreciate it but will put solved in the title.

Comment: Also you can use `r.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)` instead of a check using a if condition if a cell is blank.

Comment: You know you can use autofilter to hilde blank rows in Col H? Better than looping :)

Comment: I don't understand why some rows are excluded from your range. Having said that, a quick and dirty fix would be to loop through the entire column (or a large part of it) and then use `If IsError(Application.Match(c.Row, Array(47, 68, 131....), False)) Then` to exclude these rows from the loop

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [SOLVED] has been edited into the Title, but no solution or indication from the OP how it was solved is provided. This is not useful to future site visitors.

Comment: @Cindy Meister, I'm sorry it's in the comment section instead of a typical answer but I did provide how I was able to get around my issue in the 4th comment when I responded to Tim Stack which is why I put SOLVED in the title. I can remove the SOLVED but don't understand why if I commented how to solve this issue.

Comment: CTEAGUE212: I agree with @CindyMeister here. Just putting "Solved" in your queston title will not be of value to any other user. I happen to be online so I was able to put together an answer. In the future if there is no answer provided, either delete the question or answer your own question :)

Comment: BTW if you wish that you have a different answer, feel free to put that and aacept it (i.e if you want it) :)

Comment: Well, for one things comments are "volatile" on Stack Overflow: they can be and are often deleted, especially on older posts. In addition, the purpose of the site is a repository of information "for everyone", in a Question & Answer format - so questions and answers need to be in the right place. This isn't a "free help desk" providing support just for you :-) Luckily, Siddharth has helped us all out with a quick and thorough Answer :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code may not be working for the relevant sheet as the range is not fully qualified. `Set r = Range("H27:H46,...`. The range is referring to the activesheet.

Here is one way using `AutoFilter` which will hide the blank rows in a column. This is much faster than looping in a huge dataset.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim rngColH As Range
    Dim rngToHide As Range

    '~~> Chage this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = Sheet1

    With ws
        '~~> Remove any autofilter if any
        .AutoFilterMode = False

        '~~> Find last row in Col H
        lRow = .Range("H" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        '~~> Construct your range
        Set rngColH = .Range("H1:H" & lRow)

        '~~> Filter on blanks
        With rngColH
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="="
            '~~> These are your blank rows (i.e if there are any)
            Set rngToHide = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow
        End With

        .AutoFilterMode = False

        '~~> Hide the rows
        If Not rngToHide Is Nothing Then rngToHide.Hidden = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Here is how it works...

[image]

Using `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)` as @Mikku suggested is also a good approach :)